# System requirements for System.speech application

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, microsoft-speech-api

I am making a dumb little project for my college degree using the microsoft System.speech recognition engine. I wanted to know what were the minimum requirements for such a software to run.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The MSDN page of SpeechRecognitionEngine explains that. The supported platforms section differs when you select a different .NET Framework version from the dropdown at the top, so take a look at the list, take a look at which .NET Framework you use and see whether it's supported:

[The MSDN page of SpeechRecognitionEngine for .NET 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

- Windows 8
- Windows Server 2012
- Windows 7
- Windows Vista SP2
- Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported).

[The MSDN page of SpeechRecognitionEngine for .NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says:

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista SP1 or later
- Windows XP SP3
- Windows Server 2008 (Server Core not supported)
- Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core supported with SP1 or later)
- Windows Server 2003 SP2

[The MSDN page of SpeechRecognitionEngine for .NET 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says:

- Windows 7
- Windows Vista
- Windows XP SP2
- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Windows Server 2008
- Windows Server 2003

[The MSDN page of SpeechRecognitionEngine for .NET 3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

- Windows 98
- Windows Server 2000 SP4
- Windows CE
- Windows Millennium Edition
- Windows Mobile for Pocket PC
- Windows Mobile for Smartphone
- Windows Server 2003
- Windows XP Media Center Edition
- Windows XP Professional x64 Edition
- Windows XP SP2
- Windows XP Starter Edition